# Using async function in static methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a static method that in it I call `async` method (xmlHelper.LoadDocument()). and I call this method in a property at Setter section

```
internal static IEnumerable<Word> LoadTenWords(int boxId)
{
     XmlHelper xmlHelper = new XmlHelper();
     XDocument xDoc = xmlHelper.LoadDocument().Result;
     return xDoc.Root.Descendants("Word").Single(...)
}
```

As you know LoadTenWord is static and cannot be a async method, so I call LoadDocument with Result property. When I run my app the application don't work but when I debug it and I wait in following line

```
XDocument xDoc = xmlHelper.LoadDocument().Result;
```

everything is ok!!! I **think**, without `await` keyword, C# doesn't wait for the process completely finished.

do you have any suggestion for solving my problem?

Comment: Where is XmlHelper defined? It's not a System.Xml.Linq class is it?

Comment: I create myself it is for Windows Store app

Comment: Well, the code you posted above looks OK to me (Result should block on completion of the method), so maybe there's an issue in your XmlHelper class?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The fact that the method is `static` does **not** mean it can't be marked as `async`.

```
internal static async Task<IEnumerable<Word>> LoadTenWords(int boxId)
{
    XmlHelper xmlHelper = new XmlHelper();
    XDocument xDoc = await xmlHelper.LoadDocument();
    return xDoc.Root.Descendants("Word").Select(element => new Word());
}
```

Using `Result` results in the method blocking until the task is completed.  In your environment that's a problem; you need to *not* block but merely `await` the task (or use a continuation to process the results, but `await` is *much* easier).

Comment: you know I just forget to mention I call this method in a property

Comment: @sma That's fine:  `public static Task<IEnumerable<Word>> Words { get { return LoadTenWords(0); } }`  If you have something more complex you're going to need to provide more information.  If there's a lot more to it you may want to ask another question.

Comment: yap, I should ask another question